# Как разбирать человеческие тексты?

Tags: php, парсер, анализ

Например, есть текст подобного содержания:

> Снять с абонента «Котик» в пользу "Попугай" 30 рублей, в том числе 15 рублей за прошлый долг, 5 рублей пени, 10 рублей просто так.
> Написать отчет о действиях. Взыскать с «Котик» в доход агенства "мурчалово" 3 рубля за мурлыкание.

Из этого надо выцепить информацию в каком-нибудь подобном виде:

```json
{
  "участники": ["абонент котик", "попугай", "агенство мурчалово"],
  "взыскано": {
    "котик": [
      {
        "кому": "попугай",
        "сколько и куда": [
          {
            "сумма": 15,
            "причина": "за прошлый долг"
          },
          {
            "сумма": 5,
            "причина": "комиссии"
          },
          {
            "сумма": 10,
            "причина": "просто так"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "кому": "мурчалово",
        "сколько и куда": [
          {
            "сумма": 3,
            "причина": "за мурлыкание"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Чем это лучше делать? В какие алгоритмы копать? 100% точность не нужна, да и вряд-ли получится, но интересно как иметь хоть какую-то.

Comment: Вам знакомо понятие "машинное обучение"?

Comment: На входе просто текст или мб HTML?.. Как этот текст генерируется или откуда приходит?..

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, чисто текст.